# How can I make this SQL non sargable?

Tags: mysql

I've used an online tool to analyse one of my sql querys (The Query took me ages to make).

My query takes a word (in this example the word is 'dog.') and tries to find it in the 'qa' table when it does it joins row data from the login table where the login.pid===qa.u

```
SELECT login.pid,login.name, 
qa.id,qa.end,qa.react,qa.win,qa.stock,qa.num,qa.ratio,qa.u,qa.t,qa.k,qa.swipes,qa.d 
FROM login,qa WHERE login.pid=qa.u AND (qa.k LIKE '%dog.%' OR qa.k='.dog.') 
ORDER BY qa.d DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

I understand what the tool is telling me:

```
Argument with leading wildcard
An argument has a leading wildcard character, such as "%foo". The predicate with 
this argument is not sargable and cannot use an index if one exists.
```

but I don't know how to use an index inside the '()' without damaging or changing the results... could someone please explain how I could use an index in the middle of a query's conditions?

I take it that if this was non-sargable then the result would be faster?

Comment: actually, "Search ARGument ABLE" is when you can use an index to search, so it's faster to query. So a non-sargable query is slower.

Comment: My english is not so good. What means "sargable"?

Comment: @helle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: :) thanks, already found it... I am learning new things everyday, thanks to Stackoverflow!

Comment: the only thing relevant is the wikipedia page for Sargable https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ARGument+ABLE+mysql&oq=ARGument+ABLE+mysql&aqs=chrome..69i57.5280j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=ARGument+ABLE&safe=off

Comment: @BENZ.404 it seems the problem here is that when you do a search like %pattern in mysql, there's no way to use an index so you're actually performing a full scan. (although, if you try the quesry a second time, it will probably return your results fast because of caching) But I really don't know how to make it faster.

Comment: without knowing more about the nature of the data you have in k, all I can say to you is [1] if it's small and known, try to replace the structure to make exact queries (for example, pre-processing the tokens you want to search in a separate table) or [2] if you're searching a big free-text data (like an article) then check mysql fulltext index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use modern `join` syntax:

```
SELECT login.pid, login.name, 
       qa.id, qa.end, qa.react, qa.win, qa.stock, qa.num, qa.ratio, qa.u, qa.t,qa.k, qa.swipes, qa.d 
FROM login join
     qa 
     on login.pid = qa.u 
WHERE (qa.k LIKE '%dog.%' OR qa.k = '.dog.') 
ORDER BY qa.d DESC
LIMIT 0,15;
```

Basically "sargable" means that you *can* use an index on a particular expression (it is not an English word, it is an acronym).  The expression on `qa.k` cannot use an index.

This may not make a difference, depending on the query plan for the query.  For instance, if the engine decides to scan the `login` table and then lookup values in `qa`, the index wouldn't help.  It helps going the other way, though.

The bad news is that you cannot make this expression sargable in MySQL.  The good news is that you can use a full text index to do what you want and possibly more.  You can read about them [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  One small note is that the default settings ignore short words, up to three letters.  So you need to change the default setting if you actually want to search for "dog".

By the way, the following expression can use an index on `qa.k`:

```
WHERE (qa.k LIKE 'dog.%' OR qa.k = '.dog.')
```

(I'm not sure if MySQL actually would use the index, because it sometimes gets confused by `or`.)